# Splitting Street names with c#/regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm currently fighting (my first time) with regex.

My goal is to split multiple street names separated by "/". There are some special things to note. There could be a whitespace before and after the "/" and after the slash there needs to be a letter and not a number (because sometimes the house numbers are also separated by a slash.

I nearly archieved my goal. It currently splits as I wish when there are only two street names in a string, but with three street names I have problem (it only splits one time.)

My current two regex tries looks like this:

- /.([A-Za-z]+).*? (Works great but only with two streets, ignoring additionals)
- /.([A-Za-z]+).* (Works with multiple streets but stops after a whitespace in street names

To make it more clear I attached some screenshots:

[image: Image1]

In this screenshot I split like I want it to be (but only splits one time and ignoring the third street).

[image: Iamge2]

In this second screenshot I added a "?" at the end of the regex. Now it's considering the third street but cut's the second street after a whitespace.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Replace `.*` with `[^\/]*` (in C#, do not escape the `/`, it is only good for online testers). Also, the first `.` should be `\s*`, I believe.

Comment: Could we start from *examples*, please? Strings to split and the desired results?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your changes works great! It won't work with line breaks in the online tester, but as I don't have line breaks in my strings it doesn't matter. Thanks a lot!

DmitryBychenko Examples are in the screenshots. (I want to have each street separated in a string array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int z = 0;
string[] arr = new[]
{
    "Street name 1 / Street name 2 / Street name 3",
    "Street name 1 /Street name 2",
    "Street name 1 / 2"
};
string pattern = @"(?i)\s*/\s*(?=[a-z])";

foreach (var x in arr)
{
    WriteLine($"Record {++z}");
    var streets = Regex.Split(x, pattern);
    foreach (var street in streets)
    {
        WriteLine("\t" + street);
    }
}
/* 
   Output:

   Record 1
      Street name 1
      Street name 2
      Street name 3
   Record 2
      Street name 1
      Street name 2
   Record 3
      Street name 1 / 2
*/
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works like a charm (just needed to remove the whitespace at the end)

Comment: @Tobias I have fixed pattern - now no need to remove whitespace :)

Comment: Works! Just one word: awesome